# How do I initialize a 2D array with the users input?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function, matrix, initialization

okay so I'm new to c++ and I really need help with this assignment. So I have to basically get the users input to fill two matrices and then create functions to add, output to file, output to console and also to fill the matrix with random numbers. I've done this, however when I try to compile I keep getting these errors:

warning C4390: ';': empty controlled statement found; is this the intent?
 warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'Anum_rows' used
warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'Anum_cols' used
 warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'Bnum_cols' used
 warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'Bnum_rows' used

So What am I doing wrong? (The functions are above main and are not pictured here, but use the variables Anum_rows, Anum_cols/ Also not pictured is that I declared const max rows and columns.)

Here is the snippet for your reference:

```
 int main() {
srand((int)time(0));
int Anum_rows;
int Anum_cols;
int Bnum_rows;
int Bnum_cols;
int arr[10][10];
int b_arr[10][10];
int c_arr[10][10];
string random;
string answer;
string file;
string file_name;
ifstream fin;
while (Anum_rows == 1 && Anum_rows <= 10 && Anum_cols == 1 && Anum_cols <= 10) {



    cout << "Enter the number of rows for matrix A: ";
    cin >> Anum_rows;
    cout << "Enter the number of columns for matrix A: ";
    cin >> Anum_cols;
}

if (Anum_rows != 1 && Anum_rows != 10 && Anum_cols != 1 && Anum_cols != 10){
    cout << "Re-enter your dimensions: ";
```

Comment: Your are getting errors because you did not initialized some of your variables. How can you compare Anum_rows to something if you did not initialize it first?

Comment: what's meaning of    Anum_rows == 1 && Anum_rows <= 10 ?

Comment: @YunusKulyyev I get that, but what do I initialize them with if I don't know what the user will input?

Comment: @aminsaffar so that is to check if the number is between 1 and 10

Comment: @newbie Anum_rows == 1 && Anum_rows <= 10 this pass only when Anum_rows == 1

Comment: @newbie remove your while loop and it will work

Answer (score 0):

you may want something like this:

```
 int main() {
srand((int)time(0));
int Anum_rows;
int Anum_cols;
int Bnum_rows;
int Bnum_cols;
int arr[10][10];
int b_arr[10][10];
int c_arr[10][10];
string random;
string answer;
string file;
string file_name;
ifstream fin;
int try_times = 0;
do{

    if(try_times != 0){
        cout << "Re-enter your dimensions: ";
    }

    try_times++;

    cout << "Enter the number of rows for matrix A: ";
    cin >> Anum_rows;
    cout << "Enter the number of columns for matrix A: ";
    cin >> Anum_cols;
}while (Anum_rows > 0 && Anum_rows <= 10 && Anum_cols > 0 && Anum_cols <= 10);

//if (Anum_rows != 1 && Anum_rows != 10 && Anum_cols != 1 && Anum_cols != 10){
//  cout << "Re-enter your dimensions: ";
```

Comment: This is a good opportunity to use a `do`/`while` loop. `do { ask for input ) while (input bad);`

Comment: @user4581301 That's very nice. I forgot it when see code in question that's nice, I think if I change lower it's better to know what we do

Comment: Your answer is bad because you're repeating code unnecessarily. As the other commenter said, it's better to use a `do-while` loop.